# Acoustic Drummer Tempo to Pigtronix Infinity Looper?

Tags: midi

Is it possible for a trigger to be placed on an acoustic kick drum, so that it sends a midi clock tempo to the Pigtronix Infinity Looper?

What gear might I need to accomplish this? I'm hoping to tempo match my live acoustic drummer.

Best,
Benjamin

Comment: is the drummer playing steady quarter notes (or some other note value) the whole song? what happens if they vary what they play a bit? if they all of a sudden miss or add a beat wouldn't the tempo of the song cut in half or double? this could be dangerous.

Comment: Rock solid drummer ;) But an important consideration, and actually probably better for our poppy little numbers to just kick off a backing beat that sends the tempo out to the Infinity.

Comment: i think there is a reason you will usually have the drummer listen to the track and not the other way around. i get the desire to have the drummer be able to control the tempo, but what if he wants to play: boom bap boom boom bap. how will the trigger get the tempo from that?

Comment: Do you know of any SPD pad type thing that sends midi tempo out?

Comment: Found the Yamaha DFX Multi 12